# Versatile property referencing for Object Sorting

Tags: c#, sorting

I am facing a bit of a conundrum, and I have been unable to describe what I have in mind, when asking questions on google and StackOverflow, so please forgive me if the title is confusing!

So, my idea is to have a class called "Sort" which contains multiple different sorting algorithms in the form of methods... I have devised a way to sort values based on whether they are string, int, double, etc without having to re-type new sorts for each, but I am struggling to implement the sort because:

The list of objects I want to sort, named "Stock" contains ALOT of different properties that the program needs to be able to sort with such as date, day, and so on. What I am aiming for is not having to re-write sorts for each of the properties, but instead tell the Sort which property to look at for each object in the list... If that makes sense?

Heres my "psuedo" idea:

```
Stock[] stocksList;
Sort sort = new Sort();

stocksList = sort.Sort(sort.SortType.Bubble, stocksList, property);
```

Where SortType.Bubble is an enumerator value to determine the type of sort to perform, and property is the property name to use in each stocksList item...

Then inside the "sort.Sort" method, I want to be able to say:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stocksList.Length; i++)
{
    if (stocksList[i].property > stocksList[i + 1].property);
    {
        // Swap stocksList objects.
    }
}
```

From what I know, this isn't possible but I am HOPING someone can prove me wrong?

Thanks,
Liam

EDIT: I know that it is possible to just pass both the array of properties to analyze, and also the list of objects... But this would mean swapping values in both arrays for each sort which would basically reduce the algorithms efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You are making this way to complicated. Use the linq method orderby and pass in the key.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
SomeCollection.OrderBy((x) => x.someproperty);
```

If you really need more control, implement icomparer where you need it and you can control how the comparisons are done. There's an overload of orderBy that takes one.

Comment: It is absolutely imperative that I do not use the built in sorts, as this is for a Algorithms and Complexity assignment which requires me to write the sorts myself...

Comment: Then use the same concepts to get your flexible property handling, and Icomparer as the mechanism to handle flexible comparisons. Then just implement the sort itself yourself.

Comment: You need to modify your objects to implement IComparable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I said Icomparer. Not Icomparible. One is a helper for comparing single values, and the other makes the built in comparers able to sort your object.

Comment: I made use of System.Reflection to solve the problem after alot of headaches and late nights... Thanks for all your help though! Got me going in the right direction :)